# Push Template Dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Following is how i am creating my Template, i am trying to push template onto a ROW.
 following is my Directive,

```
  .directive('myCustomRowTemplate', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/sites/all/themes/platinum_printing/js/extjs/angular/views/campaign_script_options.html',
            }
        })
```

And i here i am trying to inject this directive("which tries calls a template"), into the DOM.

```
$scope.personalDetails = [{'add_tempalte': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',}];

$scope.addNew = function (personalDetail) {
                $scope.personalDetails.push({
                    'add_template': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',
                });
            };

$scope.addCondition = function () {
                    $scope.conditions.push('myCustomRowTemplate');
                };
```

but i am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

**Edit**

my HTML Section where i am using my Template

```
<section class="main_container">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()"/></th>
                                        <th>Setup Responses</th>
                                        <th>Add Condition</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <div ng-repeat="condition_set in conditions" my-custom-row-template> </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <input type="button" value="Add Condition" ng-click="addCondition()" class="btn btn-primary addnew"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
                                       ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</span>
```

**EDIT # 2**

```
var templateForCondtions = '<div class="table table-striped table-bordered row">' +
                        '<li>' +
                        '<select>' +
                        '<option>Response Message</option> ' +
                        '<option>IF</option> ' +
                        '<option>Else</option> ' +
                        '</select> ' +
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="personalDetail.message" required/> ' +
                        '<select> ' +
                        '<option>Step 2</option> </select> ' +
                        '<select> <option>Add Step</option> </select> ' +
                        '<a href="#">Remove Conditions</a> ' +
                        '</li> </div>';
                    $scope.conditions.push(templateForCondtions);
                    $scope.addCondition = function () {
                        $scope.conditions.push(templateForCondtions);
                    };
```

Comment: This means that $scope.conditions is undefined. Need more code

Comment: @Vitalii: please check if this works.

Comment: error on add new or addCondition ?

Comment: both, actually throw same, error. I am also not sure if what i am trying to achieve is actually possible

Comment: If you wont to create directive with custom template this is doing smth like this way http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/ also there are a lot of qa about angularjs dynamic template

Comment: @Vitalii: i just made some few changes see if this makes sense.

Comment: Did you initialize conditions at all? I am trying to find but can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and created a small example. Seems that you forgot to init your condition variable like here

```
$scope.conditions = [];
```

That's why you got undefined error. Check my code bellow - it works. And don't forget to use track by statement for ng-repeat. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) you can read more about this.

Hope this helps.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.personalDetails = [{
      'add_tempalte': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',
    }];
    
    $scope.conditions = [];

    $scope.addNew = function(personalDetail) {
      $scope.personalDetails.push({
        'add_template': '<div my-custom-row-template> </div>',
      });
    };

    $scope.addCondition = function() {
     $scope.conditions.push('myCustomRowTemplate');
    };
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="ctrl">
    <section class="main_container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <form ng-submit="addNew()">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>
                          <th>Setup Responses</th>
                          <th>Add Condition</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
                          <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="personalDetail.selected" />
                          </td>
                          <td>

                            <div ng-repeat="condition_set in conditions track by $index" my-custom-row-template> </div>
                          </td>
                          <td>

                            <input type="button" value="Add Condition" ng-click="addCondition()" class="btn btn-primary addnew" />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input ng-hide="!personalDetails.length" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="remove()" value="Remove">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right" value="Add New">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me check this please

Comment: I have another thing to ask, can we move to chat for a moment please?

Comment: @noobie-php it is hard to catch me on chat directly, so if you need any help just ask here and ill try to help

Comment: Bing for chat if you are here!